# Accessing static field: caching handles locally

Tags: java, android, performance

I have a class structure such as following for storing static final constants:

```
public final class A{
  //..list of constants
 public final class B{
  //..list of constants
  public final class C{
  // ..list of constants
  }
 }
}
```

If I need to access static constants of class C(say about 10 to them) in some thread, which of the two approaches is better(faster)? Does it even make a difference? Is this some optimization that is VM specific? I am running this code on Android platform:

```
void doIt(){
A.B.C temp;
S.O.P(temp.FIELD1);
S.O.P(temp.FIELD2);
...
S.O.P(temp.FIELD10);
}

//OR

void doIt(){
S.O.P(A.B.C.FIELD1);
S.O.P(A.B.C.FIELD2);
...
S.O.P(A.B.C.FIELD10);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first example won't compile, since you're not initializing the variable 'temp'. And since you said you're only accessing static members, instantiating it would be completely pointless.

A static final primitive will normally get inlined by the compiler, so as far as performance, it makes absolutely no difference where you get it from.